# Can you describe what is incorrect in my WPF project&

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF. This is my code for MainWindow

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">

                <RadioButton Content="Главная"
                             Height="50"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontSize="14"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                             IsChecked="True"
                             Command="{Binding ChangeToHome}"/>

                <RadioButton Content="Добавить раскраску"
                             Height="50"
                             Foreground="White"
                             FontSize="14"
                             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                             Command="{Binding ChangeToDiscovery}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and this code for MainViewModel.cs

```cs
private void ChangeToHome (object value)
{
    CurrentView = HomeVM;
    MessageBox.Show("Now in home", "alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}

private void ChangeToDiscovery (object value)
{
    CurrentView = DiscoveryVM;
    MessageBox.Show("Now in Discovery", "alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
}

private bool CanChangeView(object value)
{
    return true;
}


public MainViewModel() 
{
    HomeVM = new HomeViewModel();
    DiscoveryVM = new DiscoveryViewModel();
    CurrentView = HomeVM;

    HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeToHome, CanChangeView);

    DiscoveryViewCommand = new RelayCommand(ChangeToDiscovery, CanChangeView);
}
```

I'm not getting any errors, but nothing works. When i click on radio button there are no messages and it doesn't change the view.

Comment: Your bindigs are wrong. You bind the Command property to methods and that won't work. You must bind the Command property to a property. For example, the first `RadioButton.Command` must bind to the `MainViewModel.HomeViewCommand`. There might be more relevant code that is wrong, but as you didn't show more we can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that caught my eye was that the commands were bound to the wrong properties that were declared in the ViewModel.

[image]

[image]

There may be other errors, but to understand this you need more complete fragments of your code. Including how you instantiate the ViewModel and pass it to the Data Context.

Comment: Now is see messages, but view still doesn't change

Comment: @ArtsiomAndros The problem with bindings has been resolved.
Now you have the second problem: there is no response from the View to changing the ViewModel property. Unfortunately, in the code fragments you showed, there is nothing from which one can draw a conclusion about the causes of this problem.
I advise you to create a new topic describing this problem and show the full codes of your View and ViewModel in it. In this case, I think the error can be quickly found.